# Angular multiple rest api request

Tags: angular5

im new on Angular and have a question.
I need to call 2 API Rest, on second API i need result of first API.
I have this code:

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.Jarwis.getmyinfo()
    .subscribe(
        // data => console.log(data),
        data => this.Getmyinfo = data,
        error => console.log(error),
    );

    this.Jarwis.showazienda(id_azienda).subscribe(
        // data => console.log(data),
        data => this.Showazienda = data,
        error => console.log(error),
    );
}
```

This is a call to API rest in Jarwis:

getmyinfo(): Observable {
  return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/me`);
}

showazienda(data): Observable {
  return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/showazienda/` + data);
}

getmyinfo is first HTTP REQUEST and where i need to get id_azienda for second HTTP REQUEST (showazienda)

I think need map result of first http request in json and get result of id_azienda but im not able to do it.

If i set 1 in the parameters of showazienda im able to get and show info of API.

Answer (score 0):

For observables, you use the ".flatMap" to chain multiple async actions together (this is very similar to the promises ".then"). The flatMap allows you to used to chain multiple async requests together and have them execute one by one in order.

[Here](https://yakovfain.com/2017/09/07/rxjs-essentials-part-5-the-flatmap-operator/) is a good explanation of flatMap.

So for your example, you would do something like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.Jarwis.getmyinfo()
    .flatMap(
        (data) => {
            this.Getmyinfo = data;
            // get id_azienda from data
            return this.Jarwis.showazienda(id_azienda);
        }
    ).subscribe(
        // data => console.log(data),
        data => this.Showazienda = data,
        error => console.log(error),
    );
}
```

This example code will first send the "getmyinfo()" request. Once the response is received the ".flatMap" will be called with the data received from "getmyinfo()". You can then used this data to get the "id_azienda". Then you can make the second request to "showazienda". The observable returned from "showazienda()" needs to be returned in the flatMap. Then you subscribe to the modified observable and the data you receive will be the result from the "showazienda()" request.